# Boiling off the methanol for freeze distillation

Tags: distillation

I would like to freeze distill some hard cider I've brewed to up the gravity.  However, it is well known that freeze distillation concentrates the methanol present in the booze.

My question is, since methanol is the "first" thing that boils off during regular distillation; can I boil my cider for just a very short time to remove the methanol, cool it down, then proceed with freeze distillation?  If so, what would be the best way to go about it without losing all of my ethanol?

Comment: Some info here: https://www.homebrewtalk.com/forum/threads/minimize-methanol-in-hard-cider-and-applejack-with-heating.575080/

Comment: It does not concentrate the methanol. It removes the water. All the Apple juice get concentrated as well.

Comment: "removes water" vs "concentrates methanol".  I think that maybe this is a tomato/tomahto situation.  :)  Concentrating anything necessarily entails removing stuff that isn't that thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methanol in cider can be a problem. It's much higher in apple juice than beer. The boiling point of methanol is 148°F(64.7°C) so if you want to boil it off before the Ethanol, boiling point 173°F (78.37°C) you could do that. Bring up to temperature for a few minutes should be enough to blow off the methanol leaving most of the ethanol behind. But this might cause a pectin haze problem. In the future, doing this before fermentation will significantly reduce the levels of methanol.

I'm adding this to my answer so you all can read it at the top level

Methanol is a result of pectin breaking down into galactose units. Pasteurizing the cider and not adding any pectinase enzyme generally reduces the methanol in hard cider. Here is a [peer reviewed paper](http://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960852409013194) on the subject

Comment: How would boiling before fermentation reduce the methanol content?

Comment: Before fermentation will have zero effect, doing this once fermentation is complete would affect the levels of methanol, but I don't think you would have to worry about it.

Comment: !!! "<...>doing this before fermentation will significantly reduce the levels of methanol." Really?  Even trying to boil methanol off after fermentation would be a loss leader as some ethanol would certainly be removed too. Ethanol/methanol and water form azeotropic mixes so the distillation is not a "simple" temperature step process.

Comment: Methanol is a result of pectin breaking down into galactose units. Pasteurizing the cider and not adding any pectinase enzyme generally reduces the methanol in hard cider. 

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960852409013194

Comment: My thanks to @farmersteve. The polysaccharide pectin contains galacturonic acid which is usually found as the methyl ester. Hydrolysis of the ester produces methanol. If one denatures any natural fruit pectinase present by boiling then less methanol is produced. In practice there is some variation in this principle, but it does basically seem to be a natural source of methanol in many biological systems, including human digestion. This principle applies to many pectin rich fruits not just apples.

Comment: I thought this was common knowledge! ;-)

Comment: I don't see the science that says ethanol and methanol form an azeotropic mix. Ethanol and water form an azeotropic according to link A below from wikipedia. Methanol and water, methanol and ethanol, do not form a binary azeotropic mix however and I don't see a ternary azeotrope of ethanol, methanol, and water either. Is there something I am missing here? Other science articles posted would be appreciated explaining how there is a loss of ethanol at 64.7 degrees C. I also found this article B while writing this. I would think that a significant amount of vapor pressure would aid in the loss of

Comment: Remainder of above comment (converted from answer): of ethanol due to evaporation. Thoughts?

A https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope_tables B https://techiescientist.com/does-alcohol-evaporate/#:~:text=the%20vapor%20pressure%20of%20C2H5OH%20%28ethanol%29%20is%20calculated,understand%20the%20basic%20phenomenon%20of%20the%20evaporation%20process

Comment: methanol and water - and ethanol and water form azeotropic mixes. I must admit I have never considered what happens if one mixes both alcohols and water. I imagine  there would be two azeotropic elements but I have no idea if they themselves might further interact in some way.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't worry about it.  The methanol concentrated by freeze concentration of your cider wouldn't even be close to the acceptable amounts of methanol that's in commercial vodka.

Comment: How would you measure that to be certain?

Comment: Source? I'd be interested in reading about this

Answer (score 0):

My information has the boiling temperature at 144 degrees F. Heating your distillate to 144 will boil the methanol and tend to slow heat rise until it has finished  evaporating and before the evaporating temperature of ethanal. This is basically what happens with every still run that I've watched on moonshiners. If methanal doesn't evaporate first how is it always first out of the still. This is how they removed the methanol on the only freeze distillation show moonshiners did in 2021.

Answer (score -1):

What you are making is Apple Jack. Because you are freeze distilling all the bad stuff that you remove from first runs of your boil remains. What you end up with is the most treacherous alcohol known to man. Apple Jack goes down smooth. It is amazing on its own, it is nice with soda water or some sparkling apple juice.

You have to drink it like rich people drin cognac because you are going to want to keep drinking it but if you do it is going to hurt you. I don't lie when I say the hangover you get from this is bad... There is a reason why the hangover you get from this is called apple palsy